# Access dynamically loaded data in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following jQuery code

```
 var data2 = '';
 $.post('programs',{'tmp':data},
     function(data) {
         var str = "";

         $.each(data, function(i, program){
         str += "<option value='"+program.id+"'>"+program.sp+"</option>";
         });

         $('#form_p18').html( str );
     }
 );
```

This function works, and loads options into select field. But how I can access to value of first option in select field, and assign it to data2 variable? I need to use this variable in another function

```
$.post('words',{'spID':data2},
    function(data) {
        var str = "";

        $.each(data, function(i, an){
        str += "<option value='"+an.id+"'>"+an.word+"</option>";
        });

        $('#form_p19').html( str );
    }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick

```
var data2 = $('#form_p18 option:first').val();
```

Comment: no, it not works. With this it access loaded option on $(document).ready(), but I need access after execution of first $.post function.

Comment: @milic: that depends where are you trying to execute my code. If you put that line inmediatly after `$('#form_p19').html( str );`, you'll get the first option loaded with the `post` call.

Comment: I solved my problem with putting second $.post function inside first.